# Outlook, add a add-in command in a new Appointment Organizer

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I'm new in add-in outlook and i would like to know if it's possible to add a add-in command or a new button in a new Appointment Organizer, next to or below of reminder ?
And if yes, how ?

Thx in advance for the help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook add-ins are supported for Appointment Organizer. To activate add-ins for composing or editing appointments or meetings where the user is the organizer, include an [AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface extension point element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#appointmentorganizercommandsurface). This extension point puts buttons on the ribbon for the form that's displayed to the organizer of the meeting.

Currently, we do not support adding this button on Reminders. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions